# Ver se algum do valor do array existe numa string?

Tags: jquery

Eu estou a tentar fazer um filtro de linguagem onde ele verifica após cada tecla pressionada se existe alguma palavra não aceite.

Um exemplo, este array `['insulto1','insulto2','insulto3']`.

Como é que eu faço para verificar se alguma daquelas palavras existe no que o utilizador está a digitar?

Este é o código

```
$("#adicionar_coment").keyup(function(e){
    var nome = $("#nome_user").html();
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var html = $("#adicionar_coment").val();
    var array = [Array a cima dito]
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(html.indexOf(array[i]) >= 0){
            erro=1;
        }else{
            erro=0;
        }
    }
});
```

Com o código acima, ele só dá erro quando é igual à ultima palavra do array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que mesmo quando encontra um erro, o for continua executando, você deve parar a execução do for assim que erro = 1, além disso, vc não precisa setar o valor erro = 0 no for, apenas iniciar o erro com zero:

```
$("#adicionar_coment").keyup(function(e){
    var nome = $("#nome_user").html();
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var html = $("#adicionar_coment").val();
    var array = [Array a cima dito];
    erro = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(html.indexOf(array[i]) >= 0){
            erro=1;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Mesmo o que precisava! Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode fazer com `Regex`

```js
/* Lista de Palavrões */
const curseWords = ["word1", "word2", "word3"];

/* Textarea */
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");

/* Captura a lista de palavrões e transforma em regex */
const regex = new RegExp("("+curseWords.join("[^a-zA-Z]|").concat("[^a-zA-Z]")+")", "g");

/* Verifica os palavrões a cada letra digitada */
textarea.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  let word = textarea.value.match(regex);
  if( word ) {
    alert("Não escreva palavrões");
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\b[\w]+.$/, "****** ")
    
    console.log( word.lastIndexOf() );
  }
});

/* Verifica os palavrões quando o usuário colar um conteúdo */
textarea.addEventListener("paste", function(event) {
  event.clipboardData.items[0].getAsString(function(text) {
    var t = text.match(regex);
    
    if (t) {
      t.forEach(function(word) {
        text = text.replace( word, "******* " );
      });

      textarea.value = text;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Comment: Apesar da sua resposta estar correta, a resposta que foi aceite enquadrou-se melhor na minha pergunta, mas é sempre bom aprender outras formas